# Node.js - require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to import the mysql driver in node.js but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

This is the line that is causing the issue:

```js
//database.js
const mysql = require("mysql");
```

The file that is causing the issue is called `database.js` which I am trying to import into `script.js` using

```js
//script.js
import {myFunction} from "../database.js";
```

This is how I am importing `script.js` in HTML:

```html
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

I'm using Node.js 12.18.0

Comment: Can you provide more details? How are you running your application? What is your node version?

Answer (score 1):

You cant use CommonJs (require) in the browser, it is for Node.js.

You cant, or should not be able to use mysql stuff on the client side, this would be a big security issue.

Comment: How would I pass information from the client-side code that runs in the browser to the server-side code?

Comment: @InfiniteVortex32 well what do you want to achive?

Comment: Is it possible to make a function in Java, call it from JS, and get the return value?

Comment: @InfiniteVortex32 yes, you can archive it with AJAX and REST API